# A precise definition of contractible Banach algebras.

Tags: functional-analysis, homology-cohomology, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I am sorry if this  question is  elementary:

What  is a precise definition of a  contractible  Banach algebra?

What is  my  mistake to think that there  is  a possible (conflict)  contradictory  situation in the  following paper  and  "Wolfram" Note?:

1)Corollary 4.9 page 368 of the  following  paper:

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1962-102-02/S0002-9947-1962-0170219-7/S0002-9947-1962-0170219-7.pdf

2)Finite  dimensionality  of contractible  $C^*$  algebras as  described  here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContractibleBanachAlgebra.html

Comment: I'm not well-studied in Hochschild cohomology, but it looks like the paper only considers left-modules, while Wolfram considers bimodules.

Comment: @Aweygan  in that proposition of the paper the algebra is commutative, that is $C(X)$, so every left module can be counted as a bimodule. Right?

Comment: Sure, but can any bimodule be constructed from a left module?  For example, if $\varphi:C(X)\to B(H)$ is a representation, and we define a $C(X)$-bimodule structure on $B(H)$ by $f\cdot u=\varphi(f)u$ and $u\cdot f=u\varphi(f)$, does this naturally come from a left module?

Comment: @Aweygan  May be  I am missing something. But is  not a bimodule a left and  a  right module, already?I do not understand your comment.